# different color on Action Bar MenuItem in different configurations programmatically

Tags: java, android, colors

I want to set different colors to text of MenuItem that are in action bar and in different configurations - landscape and portrait.

I figured one way to that was have different colors set in Color and Color-land.I've made a custom theme in styles as follows

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" 
parent="android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
   <item name="android:textColor" >@color/button_color</item>

</style>
```

and then set the color black in `color` resource and white in `color-land` resource.

This would work as the activity will be created when the configuration changes.

However in my activity when the activity is created first an `AlertDialog` appears which leads to a REST api call and a `ProgressDialog` follows while the data is fetched from the server.
The problem lies in here when i would change the configuration the activity will be recreated and i will get the `AlertDialog` again.
if i set in the manifest `<activity  android:configChanges="orientation" />` the color of the menu item won't change because the activity is never created again but it will avoid the `AlertDialog` and would maintain the activity state.

I am looking for a way to change the `MenuItem` Text color in the `onConfigurationChanged` event. is there some way to do it?

Comment: Your problem is actually here: "The problem lies in here when i would change the configuration the activity will be recreated and i will get the AlertDialog again". Deal with it correctly, and you wouldn't have to mess with changing colors manually.